# Convert JavaScript type time to MySQL time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my HTML I have an input type `time`, and I want to insert this value in a column type "*time*" in MySQL using PHP. How can I do this?

```
<label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Heure de départ </span>
      <input type="time" placeholder="hh:mm" ng-model="heureDepart"><!-- datetime -->
</label>
```

The time looks like `Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+0000 (Maroc)` in HTML. I just want to save the value `(10:00:00)` in MySQL because I have a column type "*time*" in my database.

Comment: Are you asking how to send the value from the page to a PHP script? Or just how to format the time correctly using Javascript?

Comment: Show us what the time looks like from HTML then we can be specific about a date convertion mechanism

Comment: @rjdown .. yes , it s exactly what I want ( send the time value from the page to a php script )

Comment: @RiggsFolly .. I added an example of time value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, basically using the DataTime class in PHP will allow you to convert pretty much any datetime format into any other like so

```
<?php
$str = 'Thu Jan 01 1970 10:11:12 GMT+0000 (Maroc)';
try {
    $date = new DateTime($str);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

echo $date->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH :) it's exactly what I m looking for

Comment: Now , I have another problem , when I want to show a time value in my input type time selecting from database , I got this error: Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `10:00:00` to be a date

Comment: type TIME and I have an input type time too

Comment: You are going to have to show some actual code. **Which means you should ask another question** for this problem. Sorry, otherwise the answers to the original question look out of place.

Comment: okii it's okèy , I will do it right now .. but keep in your mind that your first answer solved really my first problem , still just the other side .. thank you

Comment: I actually want to put a string in input type TIME in my code html

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` in PHP. Try:

```
$time = date("format you want", strtotime("your time"));
```

Comment: I don't wanna save a date value in my bd

Comment: Still u can use the same function n convert it to the format you want.